Token-Based Authentication for WordPress e-learning Courses
I'm developing a WordPress e-learning website and need a way to control user access to specific courses and track their performance without requiring them to create accounts. I'm considering a method where I generate personalized URLs with tokens that represent the user and the course. When a user accesses the website, I'd like to check the URL and token to identify the user and track their progress.
Is there anyone who has done this? How is this possible to do, and is there anything to think of (any downsides? I know that the security for this isn't the greatest, but I'm fine with that.)

you can login a user with the wp_set_auth_cookie function. I think that the sensitive point is to manage malevolent users that will try to brut force the login.

Thanks! Any ide how i could detect which link the user is coming from?
